# How to use KeyPress event on the Form and then repass it to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, user-input

**EDITED:**
I would like to know how to use the KeyPress event on the Form, I want to write a program that the user can input values (float values) from the keyboard only by pressing the keys (number only) and this values must to be saved inside label.Text. I already tried to read the documentation [Control.KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) from MSDN I it did not helped me, I'm new in programming and because of that please explain the code you wrote (if you answer the question with code) so I can learn with it.

**I know it's possible to use the KeyPress Event in a TextBox, but it's not my objective.**

Comment: Please explain the negative votes so I can fix the question.

Comment: Hard to where to start with this. You should start simpler and go for  a TextBox with a KeyPress Handler. Learn how that works before you try to get clever.

Comment: You could just use a `TextBox` and then style it to look like a label. Sneaky little work around..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get the event from the label. because labels doesn't get focus on forms .

Fore receiving inputs from keyboard you should write your code on your form's Control.KeyPress Event  and change the keyPreview property of your form to true. so you can always get the keyboard inputs .

first set

```
yourform.KeyPreview = true;
```

and after write your code on KeyPress event like:

```
private void yourform_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //write your code here
}
```

Now you can get all the keyboard inputs on your form.

Comment: But I can get it from the Form? So I can repass it to the label?

Comment: @zignd see the example codes that I added.

Comment: How do I get the key that was pressed?

Comment: e.KeyChar is the key that pressed.